# Zend Gdata calendar retrieve events in a date range

Tags: zend-framework, gdata, zend-gdata

I am attempting to retrieve events from my calendar, the below function works to a degree but only pulls the events over the first week or so (specifically until the 24th of the first month).  I was hoping to find someone to help me figure out why.

**Here is my code**

```
$query = $service->newEventQuery();
$query->setUser('default');
$query->setVisibility('private');
$query->setProjection('full');
$query->setOrderby('starttime');
$query->setsingleevents('true');
$query->setStartMin('2013-07-14T00:00:00.000-10:00');
$query->setStartMax('2013-09-15T00:00:00.000-10:00');
$query->setSortOrder("ascending");
$eventFeed = $service->getCalendarEventFeed($query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to set `max-results` as in `$query->setMaxResults('1000');` the reason is because apparently **Google limits results to 25**.

Here is the documentation:

> Note: The max-results query parameter for Calendar is set to 25 by
>   default, so that you won't receive an entire calendar feed by
>   accident. If you want to receive the entire feed, you can specify a
>   very large number for max-results.

Found Here -> http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/reference.html#Parameters

**P.S.**
After figuring out the problem I further searched this forum with the known answer and found another similar question with the same answer, I'm listing this because honestly finding help for the **Zend Framework** and **Google Calendar Api** is not the easiest thing to do.  It would be benificial to us all if there were a more stardardize way of refferencing these two libraries-> [Google calendar query returns at most 25 entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646642/google-calendar-query-returns-at-most-25-entries)